# Error in SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat

Tags: asp.net-membership

I have the following error in my asp.net login page:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'
```

with stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()     
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)     
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)     
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)     
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e)     
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin()     
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)     
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)     
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

The error is not occured every time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your membership setting inside web.config?

Comment: <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="60">
      <providers>
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="GlobalConnectionString" applicationName="webcrm2" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>